# pandas for each group calculate ratio of two categories, and append as a new column to dataframe using .pipe()

Tags: python, pandas, pipe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame({"AAA":["x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x2"],
              "BBB":["y1","y1","y2","y2","y2","y1"],
              "CCC":["t1","t2","t3","t1","t1","t1"],
              "DDD":[10,11,18,17,21,30]})

Out[1]:
  AAA BBB CCC  DDD
0  x1  y1  t1   10
1  x1  y1  t2   11
2  x1  y2  t3   18
3  x2  y2  t1   17
4  x2  y2  t1   21
5  x2  y1  t1   30
```

## The problem

What I want is to group on column `AAA` so I have 2 groups - `x1`, `x2`.

I want then calculate the ratio of `y1` to `y2` in column `BBB` for each group.

And assign this output to a new column `Ratio of BBB`

### The desired output

So I want this as my output.

```
pd.DataFrame({"AAA":["x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x2"],
              "BBB":["y1","y1","y2","y2","y2","y1"],
              "CCC":["t1","t2","t3","t1","t1","t1"],
              "DDD":[10,11,18,17,21,30],
              "Ratio of BBB":[0.33,0.33,0.33,0.66,0.66,0.66]})

Out[2]:
  AAA BBB CCC  DDD  Ratio of BBB
0  x1  y1  t1   10          0.33
1  x1  y1  t2   11          0.33
2  x1  y2  t3   18          0.33
3  x2  y2  t1   17          0.66
4  x2  y2  t1   21          0.66
5  x2  y1  t1   30          0.66
```

### Current status

I have currently achieved it like so:

```
def f(df):
  df["y1"] = sum(df["BBB"] == "y1")
  df["y2"] = sum(df["BBB"] == "y2")
  df["Ratio of BBB"] = df["y2"] / df["y1"]
  return df

df.groupby(df.AAA).apply(f)
```

### What I want to achieve

Is there anyway to achieve this with the `.pipe()` function?

I was thinking something like this:

```
df = (df
 .groupby(df.AAA) # groupby a column not included in the current series (df.colname)
 .BBB
 .value_counts()
 .pipe(lambda series: series["BBB"] == "y2" / series["BBB"] == "y1")
 )
```

#### Edit: One solution using `pipe()`

N.B: User [jpp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9209546/jpp) made clear comment below:

> `unstack` / `merge` / `reset_index` operations are unnecessary and expensive

However, I initially intended to use this method i thought I would share it here!

```
df = (df
      .groupby(df.AAA)                     # groupby the column
      .BBB                                 # select the column with values to calculate ('BBB' with y1 & y2)
      .value_counts()                      # calculate the values (# of y1 per group, # of y2 per group)
      .unstack()                           # turn the rows into columns (y1, y2)
      .pipe(lambda df: df["y1"]/df["y2"])  # calculate the ratio of y1:y2 (outputs a Series)
      .rename("ratio")                     # rename the series 'ratio' so it will be ratio column in output df
      .reset_index()                       # turn the groupby series into a dataframe
      .merge(df)                           # merge with the original dataframe filling in the columns with the key (AAA)
      )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want the ratio of `y1` to the total instead. Use `groupby` + `value_counts`:

```
v = df.groupby('AAA').BBB.value_counts().unstack()
df['RATIO'] = df.AAA.map(v.y2 / (v.y2 + v.y1))

  AAA BBB CCC  DDD     RATIO
0  x1  y1  t1   10  0.333333
1  x1  y1  t2   11  0.333333
2  x1  y2  t3   18  0.333333
3  x2  y2  t1   17  0.666667
4  x2  y2  t1   21  0.666667
5  x2  y1  t1   30  0.666667
```

To generalise for many groups, you may use

```
df['RATIO'] = df.AAA.map(v.y2 / v.sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: how does the `.map()` work? Is it looking up the value of AAA (e.g. `x1`) in v to assign that `AAA` grouped value (`0.33333`) to the specific row?

Comment: also is there any way to make it dynamic in the case where there are many groups in `BBB`? So instead of `(v.y2 + v.y1)` in the denominator, it had many groups `(v.y2 + v.y1 + v.y3 + v.y4 + v.y5 ... + v.yn)` is there any way to sum all of those rows?

Comment: @TommyLees the map will map keys to values... as simple as that ;) as for your generalisation, you may want `df['RATIO'] = df.AAA.map(v.y2 / v.sum(axis=1))`

Comment: @TommyLees whose answer did you end up using?

Comment: I actually used yours in the end because i found it more easy to apply to my particular problem and then translate it to other calculations i wanted to do! thank you!

Comment: @TommyLees don't forget to mark it as accepted in that case. You can also upvote all answers you found helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `groupby` + `transform` with a custom function:

```
def ratio(x):
    counts = x.value_counts()
    return counts['y2'] / counts.sum()

df['Ratio of BBB'] = df.groupby('AAA')['BBB'].transform(ratio)

print(df)

  AAA BBB CCC  DDD  Ratio of BBB
0  x1  y1  t1   10      0.333333
1  x1  y1  t2   11      0.333333
2  x1  y2  t3   18      0.333333
3  x2  y2  t1   17      0.666667
4  x2  y2  t1   21      0.666667
5  x2  y1  t1   30      0.666667
```