# Pandas: calculate ratio between groups over time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    time  type   values
0   t1    type1  v1
1   t2    type1  v2
2   t3    type1  v3
3   t1    type2  v4
4   t2    type2  v5
5   t3    type2  v6
```

What I would like to create, is another column that is the ratio between the values of type1 and type2 calculated at matched up time steps, like this:

```
    time  type   values ratio
0   t1    type1  val1   v1/v1
1   t2    type1  val2   v2/v2
2   t3    type1  val3   v3/v3
3   t1    type2  val4   v4/v1
4   t2    type2  val5   v5/v2
5   t3    type2  val6   v6/v3
```

Basically I want to calculate the ratio of type1 to type2 over time.

I looked at this: [pandas for each group calculate ratio of two categories, and append as a new column to dataframe using .pipe()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892309/pandas-for-each-group-calculate-ratio-of-two-categories-and-append-as-a-new-col)

But I haven't quite been able to adapt this to my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.div` with `.map`, where the map is on the `time` column against a `"type1"` subset of `df`:

```py
df["ratio"] = df["values"].div(
    df["time"].map(
        df[df["type"].eq("type1")].set_index("time")["values"]))
```